# Apache apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed error

Tags: apache2

My apache service is giving me error, I just used a snapshop on my AWS cloud instance and everything seemed to be fine and my website was working until I restarted my apache and now it gives me the below error:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-217:/var/www$ sudo service apache2 restart
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-0-217
 * Restarting web server apache2 
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-0-0-217
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-0-0-217
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

On the user end they are getting `This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.` when they try to access the website.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us the configuration of Apache.

Answer (score 14):

I too had this problem aster a good install of Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I eventually fixed when I realised I had entered a wrong name in `/etc/hosts` file
my server name set in `/etc/hostname` was **thissrv2**

```
i.e. hosts was (after I changed it) ...
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.1.1       thissvr1
91.189.88.140   ports.ubuntu.com
91.189.95.83    ppa.launchpad.net
54.224.40.137   repo.linaro.org
```

Once I corrected the entry to that below (now in line with `/etc/hostname`) the err went

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.1.1       thissvr2
91.189.88.140   ports.ubuntu.com
91.189.95.83    ppa.launchpad.net
54.224.40.137   repo.linaro.org
```

Hope this leads others to fixing this type of error.

Answer (score 10):

This happens when apache is just installed and no setup has been done. Anyway, a quick search[1] first result provides the following reciepe:

To fix that problem, you need to edit the httpd.conf file. Open the terminal and type,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

By default httpd.conf file will be blank. Now, simply add the following line to the file.

```
ServerName localhost
```

Save the file and exit from . Finally restart the server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

[1] https://www.google.es/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=apache+fully+name&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=hYmVU-ulHI7D8gedu4EY

Comment: I tried this one but it didn't solved the issue.

Comment: Is still showing same error? Is showing more details in the logs?

Comment: also when activating vhosts pointing to 8080, you need to set the setup in /extra/httpd for the servername